Missing data impact on safety analysis
I realize this is rather vague, but I was wondering if someone can provide some good references that deal with the impact of missing data specifically on safety outcomes/analysis? I could only find very broad discussions of the impact of missing data and the general implications for the statistical analysis (almost exclusively focused on efficacy) but nothing that specifically delves into safety analysis implications/impact of missing data in the context of clinical trials.
Any thoughts/discussions/references would be greatly appreciated!
Thanks!

The best reference on missing data in clinical trials is here:
https://www.nejm.org/doi/full/10.1056/NEJMsr1203730
It is so great, in fact, FDA enfolded it into their coveted guidance documents which makes it gospel in the clinical development world. The principles and language are exactly what you'd expect in planning meetings discussing with IRBs or health authorities. As with these things, you may not always find a purpose-built answer to a specific question, but you have to use your general awareness and apply the principles to understand - no different than law, or medicine.
For instance, the major conclusion from the article is that the solution to missing data is not to have it. This sounds trivial, but in fact many protocols are poorly written and almost guarantee missing data. This is a major consideration for single arm studies - having a randomized, blinded control is the gold standard for comparing safety, especially controlling Hawthorne Effect. Most studies don't collect AEs prior to experimental therapy, even when invasive procedures are performed like a TEE or study-specific biopsies, or medications are given. Things get worse when it comes to withdrawal of consent. Even to this day, there is poor distinction between discontinuation from study and discontinuation from treatment. Discontinuing treatment is not lack of compliance, or withdrawal of consent. Take them off treatment and follow their safety events. There are funny ways this happens based on site investigator preferences as well as overly stringent study protocol requirements.

Thanks so much for the reference and your input! This is very helpful, I'll make sure to check it out in mode detail shortly.
